# Реляционная база данных. Архитектура

Tags: база-данных, архитектура, проектирование

Допустим есть таблица **"Посещений"**:
 - id, ip,
 - user_agent,
 - time .

**Вариант 1** :
   - Писать ip и user_agent как есть.

**Вариант 2** :
  - Создать отдельную таблицу для ip (id, name). 
  - Создать отдельную таблицу для user_agent (id, name). 
  В таблицу **"Посещения"** писать id ip и id user_agent'a .

В варианте **Вариант 1**
 - будет только один запрос - insert. Все.
В варианте **Вариант 2** необходимо сделать:
- найти id ip из таблицы ip, если нет такого, добавить.
- найти user_agent, и, если нет, тоже добавить.
-  И потом только insert в таблицу запросов, но, не как есть (ip, user_agent), а их id из "каталогов".
Запросов больше, но объем базы меньше в итоге.

Это все как пример более общей идеи.
 Как лучше, хранить небольшие данные (ip, к примеру) в таких "каталогах" (id, name), или все же их просто вставлять как есть?

Я вообще о принципе.
Можно допустим любые данные вынести в такие "каталоги" (id, name). 
А потом там, где нужны эти данные, искать в каталогах и вставлять id из них. Т.е. я к тому, что, в плане производительности это не накладно? Постоянно нужно сначала в каталогах искать перед вставкой куда-либо. А если без них, то просто вставка и все. Но база тогда объемнее получится. Как лучше делать, если в общем ?

Comment: в mysql для ip достаточно int использовать и преобразовывать 127.0.0.1 в число через [`INET_ATON`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton). Как в других базах - не знаю, возможно, там отдельный тип данных для этого есть. Т.е. вы одно число заменяете другим, а значит и выгоды никакой нет

Comment: user_agent и ip я бы писал как есть. В данном случае нет особого смысла городить много таблиц. Хотя конечно зависит от того какие выборки и как часто из этой таблицы будут делаться. Если пару раз в день будет собираться аналитика по user-agent, то стоит все таки сделать таблицу агентов и потом к ней еще группирующую таблицу,  которая соберет _похожих_ агентов в одного (Chrome, IE, ...) ip можно чуть ли ни строкой хранить, но если потом клеить с справочником подсетей по странам - то однозначно в виде числа, что бы потом маску наложить и подсеть проверить

Comment: записывать лог в файл. через какое-то время загружать лог в базу данных, в отдельные таблицы: ips, agents, requests

Comment: Я вообще о принципе. Можно допустим любые данные вынести в такие "каталоги" (id, name). А потом там, где нужны эти данные, искать в каталогах и вставлять id из них. Т.е. я к тому, что, в плане производительности это не накладно? Постоянно нужно сначала в каталогах искать перед вставкой куда-либо. А если без них, то просто вставка и все. Но база тогда объемнее получится. Как лучше делать, если в общем ?

Answer (score 3):

"Вообще в принципе" надо начинать с постановки задачи и описания того, что вы собираетесь с данными делать. Если вы пишете, что вам нужно сделать логирование посещений, то можно выделить две сущности: `посетитель` и `факт посещения`. `Посетитель` нужен только в случае, если он сам по себе имеет какую-нибудь информационную ценность.
Далее надо определить, что из себя представляет посетитель. Если ваш посетитель - это пользователь форума, например, которого вы идентифицируете по логину, то в таблице `посетитель` имеет смысл сделать поля `id` и `login` (как минимум, остальное по желанию). Поля `ip` и `user-agent` должны быть тогда в таблице посещений, потому что один и тот же пользователь может заходить со многих устройств.
Если посетителя вы идентифицируете только по `ip`, то особого смысла делать таблицу посетителей нет.
Что касается производительности, все зависит от того, что именно вы собираетесь делать с данными. В ситуации, пока у вас 2 - 3 таблицы, в большинстве случаев достаточно сделать индексы по полям, которые служат первичными и внешними ключами, на первое время хватит.

Answer (score 2):

Если с IP и User-agent связаны какие-то присущие именно им характеристики, то есть смысл делать для них отдельные таблицы, в противном случае (если названия User-agent не слишком длинные) это излишне.

И беспокоиться в первую очередь надо о логичности структуры базы, ее соответствии логике большинства задач, а уж потом о производительности и объеме памяти.